# What's Included in the OpenSSL 'req' Command's Message Digest (hash)?

Tags: hash, openssl

I've searched extensively to find out what get's hashed by OpenSSL's 'req' command when it generates a certificate.  Is it the Distinguished Name (DN; all fields) PLUS the certificate serial number?  Is it only the Distinguished Name? Does the hash include the Subject Alternate Name?

For certificates that get generated **using the OpenSSL 'req' command,** what parts of the certificate are included in the certificate's message digest (hash)?

Comment: what hash are you talking about? Can you show an example?

Comment: Here's the partial OpenSSL command line: openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa -sha256.  The -sha256 option specifies the value to use to hash what?  That's what my question is about - what gets hashed?